# Extracting qualified image patches in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, clip, image, extract

I want to extract qualified (e.g., cloud-free) image patches (e.g. size of 128x128) in a large image (e.g. 10000x10000) in Google Earth Engine. These image patches can overlap with other qualified patches. I will then feed these image patches to TensorFlow. Searching Earth Engine APIs, so far I only found [ee.Image.clip](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#eeimageclip), [ee.Image.clipToBoundsAndScale](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#eeimagecliptoboundsandscale), [ee.ImageCollection.getRegion](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#eeimagecollectiongetregion) that may related to my goal. But they all require some geometry or feature or feature collections in latitude/longitude coordinates as the boundary parameter.

Is there a way to extract image patches in Earth Engine like slicing sub-array of a numpy array using indices (e.g., image[0:128, 0:128])?

---

Nicholas Clinton's overall flow works. I made some minor changes to the mask and the sample steps.

For the mask step, I used the `ee.Image.fastDistanceTransform` to calculate the Chebyshev distance to pixels with non-zero value (swap 0 and 1 in a normal mask, i.e., `SwappedMask`) and create the buffered mask by setting a threshold:

```
var Chebyshev_dist_to_Mask = SwappedMask
  .fastDistanceTransform({
    neighborhood: 46,
    units: 'pixels',
    metric: 'chebyshev'
  });
var BufferedMask = Chebyshev_dist_to_Mask
  .gt(ee.Image(33))
  .select(0)
  .toByte()
  .rename('buffered_mask');
```

[image]

For the sample step, I used `ee.Image.stratifiedSample` instead of `ee.Image.sample` to sample on good pixel class only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overall flow is, you mask the image, convert to array, then sample the arrays at points.  Here's a sketch of the solution in Python (where `classes` is an image in which each pixel stores an integer label 0, 1, 2..., `composite` is some multi-band image of predictor bands and `KERNEL` is whatever shape you want:

```py
# Get only patches completely covered by the kernel.
connectedMask = classes.mask().reduceNeighborhood(
  reducer=ee.Reducer.min(), 
  kernel=KERNEL,
)

# Convert to an array per pixel
arrays = composite.addBands(classes).neighborhoodToArray(KERNEL)

# Sample the arrays
sample = arrays.updateMask(connectedMask).sample(
  numPixels=1000, 
  region=SOME_GEOMETRY, 
  scale=30)

# Export the result to a table.
task = ee.batch.Export.table.toCloudStorage(
  collection=sample, 
  description='Sample Export',
  fileNamePrefix='foo', 
  bucket=outputBucket,
  fileFormat='TFRecord', 
  selectors=listOfBands)
task.start()
```

Comment: Thanks, Nicholas. Assuming we already have the "sample", could you elaborate on how to export the array image to TFRecord format? Should I try to export these arrays pixel by pixel (i.e., in `Export.image.toDrive`, set `dimensions: 1`, `fileDimensions: [1,1]`, `skipEmptyTiles: true`, `fileFormat: 'TFRecord'`, `patchDimensions: [1,1]`, `sequenceData: true`, `maskedThreshold: 0.0`)? These settings caused a long execution time (>3 hours) before tfrecord files are generated. Besides, could you also teach me how to set `tensorDepths`? Thanks!

Comment: I've updated the answer, but not sure if that's what you were hoping for.

Comment: The overall flow works! I did make some minor changes regarding the mask and the sample steps (see the edited original question).