# Get set of 250x250 pixel tiles from an image

Tags: google-earth-engine, tiles, landsat

I am trying to split the Hansen dataset https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/UMD_hansen_global_forest_change_2018_v1_6?hl=fr
into 250x250 pixel tiles within a region.

For that I think I can use `image.clip(geometry)`, but I am not sure how I can split a region in rectangles (how to map the rectangle coordinates to the pixels) so that each of them have the desired 250x250 pixel size.

Comment: Hi Mr. Liu, what have you tried so far? include some code. What is your final goal?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/315541/extracting-qualified-image-patches-in-google-earth-engine . You possibly want to use neighborhoodToArray(KERNEL)

Comment: @RodrigoE.Principe I'm trying to get a bunch of 250x250 pixel tiles, 30m per pixel, from the Hansen Data within a specific region. I plan to feed those tiles to Tensorflow. I tried to use image.clip(geometry) but that normally requires  some sort of Geometry, so I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: @Kuik could you explain a bit how neighborhoodToArray(KERNEL) works? I'm not sure if I understand it propertly. Does it store in every pixel, a matrix with the values of the neighbors up to the size of the kernel, being that pixel the center of the matrix?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/317427/export-pixel-neighborhood-in-google-earth-engine